# Meaning of "sings low the old child's song that it has sung so many thousand years — will sing so many thousand years to come"

Tags: meaning

I'm just now started reading books. Currently starting the book [*Three Men in a Boat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Men_in_a_Boat) by Jerome K. Jerome (1889).

I am not able to understand the below bold sentence in the paragraph.

> while, in the pauses of our talk, the river, playing round the boat, prattles strange old tales and secrets, **sings low the old child's song that it has sung so many thousand years — will sing so many thousand years to come**, before its voice grows harsh and old — **a song that we**, who have learnt to love its changing face, who have so often nestled on its yielding bosom, think, somehow . . .

Comment: [correction: the sentences in bold below]. You're asking for poetry interpretation, which, unfortunately, this site frowns on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a lot of stuff going on in there. To simplify:

> *. . . the river prattles old tales and secrets — [it] quietly sings an ancient children’s song (that it has sung for thousands of years
> and will sing for thousands of years to come [before its voice grows
> harsh and old]) — a song that we, who have learnt to love its changing
> face . . .*

And to simplify further:

> *. . . the river prattles old tales and secrets — [it] quietly sings an ancient children’s song — a song that we, who have learnt to love
> its changing face . . .*

Comment: ``` a song that we, who have learnt to love the changing face``` what does it mean by changing face?

Comment: The changing face (appearance) of the river.

Comment: @Adithya: I corrected *the* to *its*, to match the author’s original text: *we, who have learnt to love **its** changing face*. That should make it clearer that it means the river’s changing face, or the changing river.